# How to add "Title" attribtue with Created By value for each reserved item in FreeBusy field table in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I searched hours on the internet, there is very few information.

**Reservations** content type is enabled in a Calendar list in SP2010(e.g. image1).

Do you guys have any ideas/directions on how to show the Creator via "tooltip/title" for each reserved/colored meeting room item in Free/Busy filed (e.g. image2)?

**Image1**

[Calendar list with content type Reservations enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzlhI.png)

**Image2**

[Showing "title" attribute with "Creator" value for reserved meeting room item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKrLS.png)